# Sort each column of the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to both react and Tailwind CSS. I've created a table like this in react:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'

const Table = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getUsers(search);
        setUsers(response.data.users);
        setPageCount(Math.ceil(response.data.users.length / pageItemCount))
        setCurrentUsers(response.data.users.slice(0, pageItemCount))
    } catch (error) { }
}, [search]);

    const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        changePage(value);
    }

    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
           
            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2'>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2'>mobile</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.first_name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.mobile}</td> 
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

Table columns are related (each name in the 1st column has a related mobile number in the 2nd column). I want to add an option on each column of this table, so that when I click on the header of that column, the rows become sorted (alphabetically and numerically). As an example, at first I have:

```
name     mobile
----     ------
Selena   236
John     123
Sam      524
```

When I click on the header of the 1st column (name), the table should be sorted like this:

```
name     mobile
----     ------
John     123
Sam      524
Selena   236
```

and when I click again, it should change to its initial state. Is there any way?

Comment: What did you try out so far?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AnindyaDey I searched a lot, but since I'm really new to react, I was not able to implement what I wanted.

Comment: @Community I edited the code and made it smaller. If anything else is needed, inform me to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort a **copy** of your `currentUsers` state, while also keeping a flag (`isSorted`) as a reference to know if the currently displayed values are sorted or not.

```
const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);
const [sortedUsers, setSortedUsers] = useState([]);

const sortFn = (userA, userB) => {
  // sort logic here, it can be whatever is needed
  // sorting alphabetically by `first_name` in this case
  return userA.first_name.localeCompare(userB.first_name)
}

const toggleSort = () => {
  setIsSorted(!isSorted)
}

// when `currentUsers` changes we want to reset our table
// in order to keep it in sync with actual values
// we're also sorting if we were already sorting
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSorted) {
    setSortedUsers(currentUsers.slice().sort(sortFn))
  } else {
    setSortedUsers(currentUsers)
  }
}, [isSorted, currentUsers])
```

Finally in your `jsx` you would use `sortedUsers` to display the data instead of `currentUsers`, as the latter is only used as the raw source and the former is the one we applied all the logic to.

If, additionally, you would want to display an icon or text to show that the displayed values are sorted (or not), you can use `isSorted` for the condition.

Comment: Would recommend against maintaining a separate state variable purely for sorted version of the array unless we know that the component isn't going to be rerendered very often or if this is the only set of data that needs to be sorted. Better imo to keep original array as is and just pass a sorted version of it down when it's needed without mutating the state.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please tell me how can I merge this in my code?

Comment: @mynameisgeoff123 agree. We could use a memorized version of the array for the sort logic or even pass it down sorted as you mention, but for the sake of this question in particular I don't want to introduce more unknown React terms to the asker.

Comment: @free what have you tried? The code above should be at the same level as your code.

Comment: @GMaiolo Since I had a `useEffect` hook myself, I didn't get how can I merge that part with yours.

Comment: @free you can have multiple `useEffect` hooks without problems

Comment: I received these messages while compiling my code: `'toggleSort' is assigned a value but never used` and `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'isSorted'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Comment: @free just updated the code a bit. You would need to add an `onClick` handler wherever you want and execute `toggleSort` in there to actually run it!

Comment: @GMaiolo So since I want to apply the sort on each column whenever I click on that column's header, I should put `onClick` handler on each header, yes?

Comment: @free I would say so, you can try it out and see if it works

Comment: @GMaiolo It didn't work for me. After adding `onClick` on column headers, whenever I click on the header, I'm redirected to a blank page.

Comment: @free You may have a link somewhere or something else in your code is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I finally became successful in running your code, the only problem is that it only sorts the columns based on the first name. How can I sort the table according to each column that I click on its header?

Comment: @free in the `sortFn` you can apply whatever sorting suits best

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the other answer. Would recommend creating a new function for the purpose of getting the sorted version of the array. You would also need to maintain a flag variable that determines if we want to show the sorted column or not that is toggled true/false when the user interacts with your column header.

```
const getUsers = () => {
   return isSorted ? currentUsers.slice().sort(sortFn) : currentUsers
}
```

In your code you would then replace the array you are currently using with a call to this function

```
{getUsers().map((item, index) => ....}
```